# How to restrict someone to View access for a GDrive folder if they're in a group with Edit access?

Tags: google-drive, google-groups, google-drive-sharing, access-control

If a Google Drive shared folder or document grants edit access to everyone in a Google Group, is it possible to restrict an individual member of that Group to view-only access?

If I:

1. Grant `Can organize, add, and edit` rights to a Google Group, and
2. Grant `Can view only` rights to a specific person,

Does #2 override or add to the #1 access rights granted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does #2 override or add to the #1 access rights granted?

No.

The only way is by removing that user from the group or to create a new group with the same members except the user that should not have edit access.